# Working with JQuery variable to reference a Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reference my checkbox element in Jquery using classname. Classname is a PHP variable whose reference I first stored in my jquery variable. When I use this variable to reference my class , variable is not getting the value. Problem will become clear with following code :

```
           <script>
            var ch='<?php echo $ch_cnt; ?>';
             $('input.'+ch).on('change', function (e) {
                if ($('input.'+ch+':checked').length > 3) {
                    $(this).prop('checked', false);
                    alert("allowed only 3");
                }
            });
          </script>
```

When I check it in developer console, I get the value inside my variable ch, but in function, instead of showing value, it shows ch as text. What wrong I am doing with it?

Comment: You are giving `json_encode($ch_cnt);` inside the `''`? What is it rendering?

Comment: what is the value of `$ch_cnt` ?

Comment: `var ch='<?php echo json_encode($ch_cnt); ?>';` this means ch is a string. Nothing more.

Comment: It's bad practice to mix Server-side lang. code in JS, especially in Event Handlers, which are executed dynamically. You can try `var ch = $(this).data('count'); $('.input.' + ch + ':checked').length` and in HTML add `data-count=count` on the checkbox.

Comment: @arve0 it is printing classname for my different sets of checkboxes which have different classnames.

Comment: @SwarnenduPaul $ch_count is a php variable used as name for checkbox class.

Comment: @tushar I have different sets of dynamically generated checkboxes which need this functionality.

Comment: @AmBhar if it is just a class name then no need to encode it in json

Comment: @SwarnenduPaul I was just trying out different things. Removed the encoding, still same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
         $("input.<?php echo $ch_cnt; ?>").on('change', function (e) {
            if ($("input.<?php echo $ch_cnt; ?>:checked").length > 3) {
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
                alert("allowed only 3");
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Foolish of me to complicate things for myself. Your solution is simple and works well. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `<?echo json_encode($ch_cnt) ?>` inside quotes. `json_encode()` puts quotes around strings for you, so you'll get an extra set of quotes in the Javascript value. The whole point of using `json_encode` here is that it will output the appropriate syntax for a Javascript literal, you don't need to quote it.

```
var ch=<?php echo json_encode($ch_cnt); ?>;
```

Since you're repeating this code, you need to put the Javascript inside an IIFE, so the scope of `ch` is limited to that function.

```
    <script>
    (function(ch) {
        $('input.'+ch).on('change', function (e) {
            if ($('input.'+ch+':checked').length > 3) {
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
                alert("allowed only 3");
            }
        });
    })(<?php echo json_encode($ch_cnt); ?>);
    </script>
```

Comment: If `$ch_cnt` is number, then even `json_encode` is not required. I still don't understand why `ch` is used as String value, instead of variable.

Comment: @barmar I am getting value inside ch variable, the problem is value is not passing inside the function, is there any problem with syntax ?

Comment: Do you have multiple repetitions of this code? If you do, then you'll change the value of `ch` each time. And when the function runs, it will get the most recent value. You can solve that by wrapping it in an IIFE so they each have their own scope.

Comment: Yes there is multiple repetetion. Value of ch keep on incrementing like 1,2,3 and so on inside var ch=<?php echo $ch_cnt; ?>; BUT not used inside Jquery function

Comment: I've added the IIFE to the answer.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. It worked. The problem was with the scope of variable.